# How to call command inside listbox in silverlight4

Tags: xaml, data-binding, silverlight-4.0

I am using Listbox and it contains button ,and i want to handle button click event using command.but my command never calls.

is this Correct way??

```
  <pmControls:pmListBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}" >
                <pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Button Command="{Binding GetAllStatesCommand}"   CommandParameter="{Binding}" Margin="3" Width="100" Height="50" Content="{Binding Title}">                                                                                                                                
                        </Button>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </pmControls:pmListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataContext` of one list item is different from the `DataContext`of the surrounding control. To bind that command to the `DataContext` of that control you have two options:

Either you provide the control with a name and reference to that:

```
<pmControls:pmListBox x:Name="myCoolListBox" [...]>
    <pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.GetAllStatesCommand, ElementName=myCoolListBox}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" [...] />                                           
        </DataTemplate>
    </pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate>
</pmControls:pmListBox>
```

Or you create class holding your `DataContext`...

```cs
public class DataContextBinder : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Context", typeof(object), typeof(DataContextBinder), new PropertyMetadata(null));
    public object Context
    {
        get { return GetValue(ContextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

...and create an instance of that in the resources section of your `ListBox`:

```
<pmControls:pmListBox x:Name="myCoolListBox" [...]>
    <pmControls:pmListBox.Resources>
        <local:DataContextBinder x:Key="dataContextBinder" Context="{Binding}" />
    </pmControls:pmListBox.Resources>
    <pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding Context.GetAllStatesCommand, Source={StaticResource dataContextBinder}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" [...] />                                           
        </DataTemplate>
    </pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate>
</pmControls:pmListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks it Works But Now My command calls but again it looses previous binding which i given to listbox :                         ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry}"   and i didnt get Selected object??

Comment: Please see my modified answer - you will of course only get the item as command parameter if you bind id. Whereever you find `[...]` in my code I left you some of yours to improve readbility...